# Error importing sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA macro to import a sheet from another workbook. I get a "subscript out of range" error on the "copy" line. The file opens correctly, but I'm not sure what goes wrong after that.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastdate As String, filename As String

lastdate = Format(sheet_1.Range("D11") - 7, "ddmmyy")
filename = "C:\Dir\file " & lastdate & ".xlsm"

Workbooks.Open (filename)
Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(2).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Workbooks(filename).Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Edit: error changed to "subscript out of range", code changed so worksheets referenced by index.

Code v2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastdate As String, filename As String

lastdate = Format(sheet1.Range("D11") - 7, "ddmmyy")
filename = "C:\Dir\file " & lastdate & ".xlsm"

Dim wbk As Workbook
wbk = Workbooks.Open(filename)

wbk.Worksheets(2).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
wbk.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: where are `sheet_3` and `sheet_1` dimensioned and what datatype and values are they?

Comment: This is me trying to prevent you from closing without saving: I think you want `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end. Plus, you should always do error handling when setting that to `False` else you're headed for bad surprises fast.

Comment: Hi, I have edited above. I had used sheet_3 and sheet_1 as placeholders in simplifying down the code a little, and that was causing part of the error. However, there is still an underlying problem - when I do the same using indices I get a "subscript out of range" error (which I think was the original error).

Comment: Jean-Francois, you're right. Sorry, a typo!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett `Application.DisplayAlerts`. according to Help, "If you set this property to False, Microsoft Excel sets this property to True when the code is finished, unless you are running cross-process code."

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I stand corrected! Then I guess the lesson is, don't clutter your code with `Application.DisplayAlerts = ...` at the end. Same goes for `ScreenUpdating`, by the way. Gets set back to `True` automatically at the end.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett you are so right with that ... but dom't let anyone be fooled by inferring from our comments that the same applies to `Application.EnableEvents`. That definitely **Does not reset itself**. Put it down to "Undocumented features".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett what alert is being suppressed in this method? I use it when deleting a sheet but on testing the method given in OP there are no alerts.

Comment: @whytheq: Save before closing, maybe? Or maybe the OP only showed part of the code? I don't know. Ask the OP.

Comment: what alert is being suppressed in this event procedure? If you omit `Application.DisplayAlerts = ...` then does that make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the subscript out of range error because you don't have the workbook's `Name` right. The `Name` isn't the same thing as the full path (which is what you have been assuming); it's the same thing as the filename.

This will work:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Dir\file1234.xlsm"
Workbooks("file1234.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("a1").Value = "yay"
```

Whereas this won't:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Dir\file1234.xlsm"
Workbooks("C:\Dir\file1234.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("a1").Value = "yay"
```

But a much better way to reference a workbook is to set an explicit reference to it like this:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(filename)
wbk.Worksheets(2).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

With `wbk` you now have a handle on the workbook you want; you don't have to guess its name or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword 'Set' is required when referencing an object variable:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<<this does not look like it is required - when is an alert displayed in the method?

Dim lastdate As String, filename As String

lastdate = Format(sheet1.Range("D11") - 7, "ddmmyy")
filename = "C:\Dir\file " & lastdate & ".xlsm"

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(filename)   '<<Set is required

wbk.Worksheets(2).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
wbk.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_Worksheets()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FolderPath = "H:G:\D S Class\Excel VBA (Macro)\RTO form\VBA\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "RESTAURANT_USAGE_DATA.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Next sheet
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

    enter code here
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks